# Xilinx Alveo U50 ES3 FPGA, FPGA_RXD_MSP pin meaning?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I found on https://github.com/Xilinx/XilinxBoardStore/blob/2020.1.1/boards/Xilinx/au50/production/1.0/part0_pins.xml

two pin names I dont understand. What are purpose of

```
<pin index="9"   name ="FPGA_TXD_MSP"  iostandard="LVCMOS18" loc="BB25"/>
<pin index="10"  name ="FPGA_RXD_MSP"  iostandard="LVCMOS18" loc="BB26"/>
```

in line 29?

Best'

Answer (score 0):

I have found some information about the pin on the [alveo product guide](https://eu.mouser.com/pdfDocs/u50-UserGuide.pdf), section *Maintenance Connector Interface*, which I quote:

> The Alveo U50 accelerator card provides access to the FPGA through the
> JTAG interface using a debug and maintenance board (DMB) connected to
> the 30-pin maintenance connector. The connector pinout supports three
> UART debug interfaces: PMBus, FPGA JTAG, and satellite controller
> JTAG.

(From here you can dive deeper into the [UG1377](https://www.xilinx.com/cgi-bin/docs/bkdoc?k=accelerator-cards;v=2019.2;d=ug1377-alveo-programming-cable-user-guide.pdf))

By looking at another [u50 alveo PG](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/data_sheets/ds965-u50.pdf) we can find more info about the satellite controller (page 5).

> A TI MSP432 satellite controller resides on the U50/U50 LV card to
> control and monitor voltages, currents and temperatures

By looking at the picture, [image], it seems that the PINs you are searching for are UART pins (TX,RX) to communicate to the TI satellite controller from directly the FPGA.